# Chrome driver 2.28: "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" notification. Can it be removed?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I have just updated my project with the latest chrome driver (2.28).
When I run the browser through the driver, a yellow notification pops under the URL bar, saying "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software". 
Is there any way to configure Chrome not to show this notification?

I used this code to start the driver:

```
    ChromeOptions cOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    cOptions.addArguments("test-type");
    cOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
    cOptions.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
    cOptions.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
    cOptions.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    cOptions.addArguments("--disable-default-apps"); 
    driver = new ChromeDriver(cOptions);
```

---

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try `cOptions.addArguments("test-type=browser");`

Comment: Also try removing `cOptions.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");` and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have any idea to disable the info-bar while running script in chrome emulator?

Comment: Any ideas how to do it for Robot Framework?

Answer (score 17):

Just in case someone sees that post , I added :

```
cOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Arrays.asList("enable-automation"));
```

And it caused the driver to crash when calling:

```
driver().manage().window().maximize();
```

So I had to remove it.
Anyway , Adding :

```
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

solved the original issue.
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Solution for Python 3:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver,chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
```

Also, it's better to use `Collections.singletonList` instead of `Arrays.asList` since we are passing in a single argument to `excludeSwitches`.

Disabling the infobar using `--disable-infobars` flag will suppress other useful information in the future and is not recommended as @michaeldurrant suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it by passing the "disable-infobars" argument:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
WebDriver player = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: hmm, very global.  Might cover up crucial information in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The [infobar was added](https://codereview.chromium.org/2564973002) in the most recent [Chrome update](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2017/03/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html):

> Add an infobar if a session is being controlled by an automated test.
>
> This infobar is only displayed if the browser is launched with the
> --enable-automation switch. It also disables the developer mode extensions
> warning bubble.

To disable it, remove the switch like so:

```
ChromeOptions cOptions = new ChromeOptions();
cOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Arrays.asList("enable-automation"));
_driver = new ChromeDriver(cOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

In chrome 57+ and chromedriver 2.28, the execution was not starting when `driver.manage().window().maximize();` is used

Solution:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-incognito");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();    
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver webDriver = new <strike>ChromeDriver</strike>(capabilities);//Capabilities is deprecated in latest version
```

***Don't Use*** `driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Answer (score 1):

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Comment: It does not work with Chrome 65 and Chrome driver 2.33 or 2.36.
Do we have any solutions for this case, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for Ruby with Capybara:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, args: ["--disable-infobars"])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , I added :

```
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

I also added :

```
cOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Arrays.asList("enable-automation"));
```

Just to make sure nothing pops in the future.
It looks like the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using :

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(browserFolder);
```

it did not dismiss the pop-up. I'm using selenium webdriver with C#.

Comment: what is browserFolder and where you pass option?